# Yii2 pjax corrupts styles

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, pjax

I'm using Yii2 and i have a view which displays a table:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<?php  yii\widgets\Pjax::begin()?>    
<?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'summary'=> "",
            'tableOptions' => ['id'=>'smartTable',
                'class' => 'display table-bordered-custom',
                'cellspacing' => 0,
                'width' => "100%"
                ],
            'columns' => [
                [
                  'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],    
                  'product_code',
                  'product_name',
                  'product_status',    
                   [
                    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                    'header' => 'Operation',
                    'template' => '{view}',
                    'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'no-sort'],
                    'buttons' => [
                        'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                            return Html::a(
                                'Edit<i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>',
                                ['update', 'id'=>$model->product_id],
                                [
                                    'class' => 'btn',
                                    'data-pjax' => '',
                                ]
                            );
                        },
                    ],
                ],
            ],    
]);    
?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>    
</div>
```

My controller:

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::class,
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * Lists all Product models.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Product::find(),
        'sort' => false,
        'pagination'=> [
            'pageSize' => 4
        ]
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
}
```

**Edit**: My controller has a simple action called index.

My problem is that when i click on the page number and get new info, all the styles I've given to my table disappear.
If i remove *Pjax* everything is okay because the entire page reloads.

Why? please help me.

Comment: can you add you controller action too ?

Comment: Hi @Omer Aslam, I added my controller but the problem is in **view** not another place.

Comment: yes just wanted to be sure it works correctly for me though, i just tested it can you confirm what version you are on of `Yii` and for once clear the `web/assets` directory.

Comment: also can you add an image of how it looks like and does the `console` shows you `404` for the `css` files when page reloads?

Comment: I'm using **Yii 2.0.14.1** and also removed my assets and no error occurs but the problem has not been resolved yet

Comment: No error occurs in the `console`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to fix this! but i'm not sure it's the best.
With **pjax events** you can solve such problems:

```
$(document).on("pjax:success", function() {
 $('#smartTable').DataTable({
     "paging": false,
     "responsive": true,
     "dom": 'iftlp',
     "bProcessing": true,
     "aoColumnDefs": [ // EXCEPT SORTING
         {'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': ['no-sort']}
     ],
     });
 $('#simpleTable').DataTable({
     "responsive": true,
     "dom": 't'
 });
});
```

So every time our `pjax` is successfully executed, we will re-apply the style we need.
That's it, i hope to be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to pjax that we can reload selective content easily.

## Issue

In Yii2, pjax also do try to loads the anchors (links) etc present inside the pjax container within the same container. Which means it doesn't allow such links to load, full pages. This causes crippling of the other parts / tags in followed pages.

## Solution

In order to avoid this, you need to figure out a way to load your links/pages outside the pjax container. One method that worked for my action links is as following:

## Example

This is my custom actions column:

```
[
'label'=>'Options',
'format' => 'raw',
'value'=>function ($data) {
return Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>', ['short-message/conversation', 'id'=> $data["id"]], ['onclick' =>'window.location.href=this.getAttribute("href")']);
},
],
```

## Explanation

You can see that I have used onclick method to follow the link using JavaScript:

```
 ['onclick' =>'window.location.href=this.getAttribute("href")']
```

Comment: If someone can post such alternative solutions, it will be great favour. Also you can suggest any way to turn off the pjax's anchor tag / links capturing feature.
Thanks @MHF ,  although your solution was temporary and not general one but it led me to figuring out the actual issue.